# Call to a member function fetchAll() on null

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on null
I am base on this code: https://github.com/roggeo/zfblog

Controller:

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
        $users=$this->table->fetchAll();
       foreach ($users as $user){
           echo $user->getName().'<br/>';
       }
    }
```

Connect to DB:

```
return [
    // ...
    'db'=>[
        'driver'=>'Pdo',
        'dsn'=>'mysql:dbname=blog;host=localhost;charset=utf8',
        'username'=>'root',
        'password'=>''
    ]
];
```

Class UserTable:

```
protected $tableGateway;
public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}
public function fetchAll()
{
    return $this->tableGateway->select();
}
```

Get controller config:

```
 public function getControllerConfig(){
        return [
            'factories'=>[Controller\IndexController::class=>function($container){

                return new Controller\IndexController(
                    $container->get( Model\UserTable::class)
                );
            }]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: How does `$this->table` get populated?

Comment: Does your Module.php file contain the function `getControllerConfig()`?

Comment: Yes. See the update of the post